# Error at Import Identity History OLE DB Source Output contains no output columns

Tags: ssis

I'm getting the following error and I don't know why.  I am totally new to SSIS so bear with me.

### TITLE: Package Validation Error

Package Validation Error

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at Import Identity History [SSIS.Pipeline]: The "runtime connection "OleDbConnection" (10)" in the connection manager collection, Connections, of "component "OLE DB Source" (1)" does not have a value for the ID property. Verify that the ConnectionManagerID property of the runtime connection object has been set for the component.

Error at Import Identity History [SSIS.Pipeline]: component "OLE DB Source" (1) failed validation and returned error code 0xC004801C.

Error at Import Identity History [SSIS.Pipeline]: "output "OLE DB Source Output" (11)" contains no output columns. An asynchronous output must contain output columns.

Error at Import Identity History [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.

Error at Import Identity History: There were errors during task validation.

(Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I assume the package was created pointing to a source with a format X and now that same source has a format Y so it is complaining the sources are different (in this case the column ID is missing)

or maybe the connection manager used on the compenent is missing...

Answer (score 0):

Select a input table for OLE DB Destination.